# Get Multiple pages of data at once with Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pagination, backbone.js-collections

I have this Collection mixin that I'm using to attempt to continue to pull multiple pages of data into the collection **together**, but I assume it resets itself when it detects new options passed into fetch as I'm only ending up with the last page of data.

```
var Pageable = {
  fetch: function(options) {
    var originalSuccess = options.success;
    options.data.page = 1;

    var doFetch = function(options) {
      var beforeLength = this.length;

      options.data = _.extend({page: options.data.page, per_page:100}, options.data);
      options.success = function(col, res, opts) {
        if (this.length === beforeLength) return originalSuccess(col, res, opts);
        options.data.page++;
        doFetch(options);
      }.bind(this);

      return Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
    }.bind(this);

    return doFetch(options);
  }
};
```

I think from this you get the gist of what I'm trying to do, any ideas as to how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,  you need to add options to tell the collection to not remove, but only add/update...

```
var Pageable = {
  fetch: function(options) {
    var originalSuccess = options.success;

    _.extend(options, {
      add: true,           // <----
      remove: false,       // <----
      update: true,        // <----
      data: {
        page: 1,
        per_page:100
      }
    });

    var doFetch = function(options) {
      var beforeLength = this.length;

      options.success = function(col, res, opts) {
        console.log(this.length, beforeLength);
        if (this.length === beforeLength) return originalSuccess(col, res, opts);
        options.data.page++;
        doFetch(options);
      }.bind(this);

      return Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
    }.bind(this);

    return doFetch(options);
  }
};
```